# Android - Having troubles displaying\dismissing a progress dialog while using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm making a url request using `AsyncTask`, and want to display some sort of progress spinner while the request is processed. The `AsyncTask` class is located within another Activity `VerificationActivity` which extends `Activity`. The app crashes on this line: `dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);` Probably the problem is with the `context` of the app, I tried `VerificationActivity.this` and creating a local instance of `VerificationActivity` and passing it as a context.

```
        SmsTask smsTask = new SmsTask(VerificationActivity.this);
    /*
    * some code
    */
 class SmsTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Boolean> {
    final AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Context mContext;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    SmsTask(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pd.setProgressStyle(AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        pd.show(mContext,"Please wait","Sending...");
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            b.set(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // result holds what you return from doInBackground
        if(pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        Log.i("result from async: ",""+result);
    }
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

UPDATE:
I fixed the `context` issue based on the answers here, and ran a test, simulated some heavy work inside the `doInBackground` method using the `Thread.sleep()` method, but the progress spinner still doesnt show. Any ideas?

UPDATE2:
I managed to show the progress dialog as i need, but now im not able to dismiss it. I assume it is because I cant dismiss UI elements, do i need to run the progress dialog inside `runOnUIThread`?

Comment: Please add constructor like  
private SmsTask(Context context){
      this.mContext = context;
    }

Comment: Thanks. What do I pass as the context to the constructor of  `SmsTask smsTask = new SmsTask();` ?

Comment: Pass your Activity. For example your activity is like VerificationActivity then
SmsTask smsTask = new SmsTask(VerificationActivity.this);

Answer (score 1):

I assume you pass the activity as context and by the time the task is going to be executed, the activity might be gone and the you'll get `NullPointerException`, so 2 options you have;

1. Check for the context- of it's null you might not need the loading dialog at all
2. Use the Application context

Comment: Basically I think I need that progress bar for slower connection types. With a strong signal this request might go through quickly, but with slower connection types i need some kind of indication.

Comment: I'm just saying that if the Activity not exist so it not visible and the user not seeing this screen. So you need to think on another UI solution (show it on another activity, or as a sticky notification)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see below the updated AsynTas.

```
class SmsTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Boolean> {
    final AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private SmsTask(Context context){
      this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("executing Pre - execute","");
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext );
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //.... dosing stuff
        return b.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then Whats the context I need to pass to the constructor of `SmsTask smsTask = new SmsTask();` ?

Comment: You have to pass this or getApplicationConext() method of activity.

Comment: Hi can you pass getApplicationContext() instead of VerificationActivity.this activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Context context;
```

you have defined context here, but you didn't initialize it. You can initialize it by a constructor

```
 public SmsTask(Context con){
      context = con;
    }
```

and when you call your SmsTask pass context to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed the context issue, but the spinner doesnt show.

Comment: are you sure you are calling the right AsyncTask, post the code where you call AsyncTask.

Comment: The code that's calling the AsyncTask is there, its in the first line. Please note that i managed to show the progress dialog, but now i cant dismiss it.

Comment: if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }

Comment: Progress dialog still doesnt stop :\

Comment: do one thing, just write System.out.println("Hello"); and remove everything else and return statement in your doInBackground and see if progressDialog dismisses.

Comment: No, still doesnt dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the application context - 
`dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());`

Comment: Yes i passed the context to the `ProgressDialog`, still no go. Doesnt show.